# Finding even numbers from randomly generated numbers

Tags: java

I have a java program which starts like this:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random r = new Random();

    int n = r.nextInt(10);
    int m = r.nextInt(15) + 20;

    System.out.println("n: " + n + ", m: " + m);
```

Now, I must create a code which will bring me only even numbers from n and m respectively. I have tried for in if statements, but have only got one number from each.

I am new to programming so even the basic things are quite difficult.

EDIT: I have tried this, but it only brings two randomly generated numbers and I must get all even numbers:

`if (n%2==0);
    System.out.println(n);
    n++;
if (m%2==0);
    System.out.println(m);
    m++;`

Comment: What do you mean by "bring me only even numbers from n and m respectively"? You're only generating two numbers... so it's also not clear what you mean by "only got one number from each". Please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: And include your attempt to solve that part of the problem, and explain where you're stuck. The code above just creates the numbers, there's nothing that's trying to output the even numbers between them.

Comment: The code above is fixed, I cannot change it. Sorry i forgot to mention it.

Comment: Using `if(n%2==0) n++;` will ensure n is odd, not even.  Do note that you should not have a semicolon after an if statement, and to surround the contents with curly braces when spanning multiple lines: `if(n%2==0){System.out.println(n); n++;}`

Comment: Thank you for that advice, as I said, nearly everything is new for me. This is part of mandatory course I'm taking. I have never before coded so I'm really a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure what is going on with your code, but I do have a solution for you.  You can implement it in any way you want to.

If a number modulus 2 equals zero, it is even.

```
Random r = new Random();
int a = r.nextInt(10);
if(a%2==0) System.out.println("EVEN");
```

So if you want random even numbers, you can do this.

```
int num = r.nextInt(10);
while (num % 2 != 0){
    num = r.nextInt(10);
}
System.out.println(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like:

```
int n = 2*(r.nextInt(5));
int m = 2*(r.nextInt(7)) + 20;
```

You'll always get n and m, even

Comment: This won't work if you need to keep the numbers within their given bound.

Comment: @Brandon I'think now the numbers remain in bound

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();

        int n = r.nextInt(10);
        int m = r.nextInt(15) + 20;

        while (n%2 != 0 && m%2 !=0 ) { 
            int n = r.nextInt(10);
            int m = r.nextInt(15) + 20;
        }

        System.out.println("n: " + n + ", m: " + m);
    }
}
```